# How i can change fragment with switch button?

Tags: android, kotlin, tabs, android-tablayout

Kotlin project has Tab Layout with Different Fragments (FirstTab1, SecondTab1, ThirtTab1, FourthTab1, FifthTab1), In the activity_main.xml is button id "button1". How can I replace those fragments with other (FirstTab2, SecondTab2, ThirtTab2, FourthTab2, FifthTab2) using the switch button

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val fragmentAdapter = MyPagerAdapter1(supportFragmentManager)
    viewpager.adapter = fragmentAdapter

    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewpager)


}
```

MyPagerAdapter.kt

```
class MyPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter
(fm, FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {

override fun getItem( position: Int): Fragment {

    return when (position) {

        0 -> FirstTab1 ()
        1 -> SecondTab1 ()
        2 -> ThirtTab1 ()
        3 -> FourthTab1 ()
        else -> FifthTab1 ()
        }
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return 5
}

override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
    return when (position){
        0 -> "poniedziałek"
        1 -> "wtorek"
        2 -> "środa"
        3 -> "czwartek"
        else -> return "piątek"
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mystud.riki">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Tab example

```
class FirstTab1 : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first_tab1, container, false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take an action in your id Button and use "setCurrentItem" in your id ViewPager. ( For example, go to "**SecondTab1**" )

```
[your id Button].setOnClickListener {
   [your id View Pager].setCurrentItem(1, true)
}
```